# How to rename a document field of a nested array in mongodb in c#

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

given a collection with the following documents in MongoDB:

```
{
  id: guid,
  items: [
    {
      fieldA : "value"
      ...
    },
    {
      fieldA : "value"
      ...
    },
  ]
},
{  ...
}
```

I must to find an efficient way to rename *fieldA* to *fieldB* using C#.
It seems to me that MongoDB does not provide a rename operator usable with arrays.

I tried the path to add a new field to the array, but I do not know how to set that field to the value of the old one.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is your MongoDB version?

Comment: the version is 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no typesafe way of currently achieving this in MongoDB Driver [2.10.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/2.10.4). However, you can build up an aggregation pipeline with a `$map` and execute it as an update pipeline.

```cs
var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = db.GetCollection<MyClass>("data");

var filter = Builders<MyClass>.Filter
    .Empty;

var update = Builders<MyClass>.Update.Pipeline(
    new PipelineStagePipelineDefinition<MyClass, MyClass>(
        new PipelineStageDefinition<MyClass, MyClass>[]
        {
            @"{ ""$addFields"": {
                  items: {
                    $map: {
                      input: ""$items"",
                      as: ""item"",
                      in: {
                        fieldB: ""$$item.fieldA""
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }"}));

await collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This works by running the pipeline and updating each document with the output of the pipeline, the above is a simple pipeline that replaces the `items` field with a new `items` field with a new array mapped from the old array.

Comment: I tried this out on some test data and it seems to wipe out any other fields you have in that array collection, leaving only the renamed field in the array. I believe you need to include a mapping for every field you want to keep in the "in" section. The original question implies there is more than just fieldA.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Kevin Smith's answer, here's a helper function which also maps all the existing fields and only performs the change on records where the old field name exists in the array.

A few things to keep in mind using this function, this is just single level depth and this doesn't handle the situation where some fields are partially converted, though the latter should never be a thing in the first place.

This uses the new raw strings feature in C# 11 to make life easier.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// NOTE: YOU CAN LOSE DATA IF TArray PUBLIC PROPERTIES DO NOT INCLUDE ALL FIELDS IN THE MongoDB ARRAY <para />
/// Helper to rename a field for all values in an array such as <br />
/// { arrayItems: [ { "fieldNameA": "fieldValue" }, .... ] } <br />
/// TO <br />
/// { arrayItems: [ { "fieldNameB": "fieldValue" }, ... ] }
/// <remarks>
/// <typeparamref name="TArray"/> type is required to allow mapping all other fields.
/// </remarks>
/// </summary>
public async Task RenameFieldInArray<TCollection, TArray>(IMongoCollection<TCollection> collection,
    string arrayFieldName, 
    string oldFieldName, 
    string newFieldName)
{
    var filter = Builders<TCollection>.Filter.Exists($"{arrayFieldName}.{oldFieldName}");

    // map all unspecified fields in the existing array
    var arrayPropertyNames = typeof(TArray).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(x => !string.Equals(x.Name, oldFieldName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && 
                        !string.Equals(x.Name, newFieldName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .Select(x => $"{x.Name}: \"$$arrayItem.{x.Name}\"");
    var otherFieldMapping = string.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, arrayPropertyNames);

    var update = Builders<TCollection>.Update.Pipeline(
        new PipelineStagePipelineDefinition<TCollection, TCollection>(
            new PipelineStageDefinition<TCollection, TCollection>[]
            {
                $$"""
                 { "$addFields": {
                     {{arrayFieldName}}: {
                       $map: {
                         input: "${{arrayFieldName}}",
                         as: "arrayItem",
                         in: {
                           {{newFieldName}}: "$$arrayItem.{{oldFieldName}}",
                           {{otherFieldMapping}}
                         }
                       }
                     }
                   }
                 }
                 """,
            })
    );
    
    await collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

// Assuming 'Items' is the type mapping for the array of items in 'MyClass'
await RenameFieldInArray<MyClass, Items>(MyClassCollection, arrayFieldName: "items", oldFieldName: "fieldA", newFieldName: "fieldB");
```